# Changing font depend on select option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a lot of willpower but hard to implement them. This is one of them. I have input form called `caption` :

```
<input id="caption" type="text" name="caption" placeholder="Caption" maxlength="30"/>
```

And i using `.onkeyup` to show the value from `caption` input :

```
<!-- This code showing "caption" value -->
<span id="print" class="date-container"></span>
```

Now, i want to change the font of the `caption` using `select option` tag :

```
<select id="font" name="font">
   <option value="kalam" selected="selected">Kalam</option>
   <option value="handlee">Handlee</option>
   <option value="pacifico">Pacifico</option>
</select>
```

My problem is, how do i change font-family depend of option value selected ?

Example : 
i inputing value on `input caption field` and it automatically showing up at `date-container` then i want to change the default font to another in `select option`. But keep the `caption` showing up, so it just change the font-family. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your attempt to change the font?

Comment: @NewToJS I don't know how to do, so i asked it..

Comment: Okay, well maybe something like this will help if you want a pure javascript solution. https://jsfiddle.net/xauu3agn/ If you already have jQuery then Farzin Kanzi's answer will be much shorter/cleaner to use but I would recommend doing some research and try something of your own, then submit a question with the source code you're having problems with.

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks! more answer more knowledge i learn ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need js or jquery:

```
<script>
   $('#font').change(function(){
     $('#caption').css('font-family', $('#font').val());
   });
</script>
```

Add a jquery file up of your page, In the `<head>` tag add this:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

and cope my code after the select and text box.

Comment: Thanks! its look easy for you.. Hard to implement this problem for me :(

Comment: You welcome. But with my bad english i did not understand did it work? :)

Answer (score -2):

There is a `checked` CSS pseudo selector.

```css
option:checked {
    font-family: fantasy;
}

option {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How does this change the font or in any way answer the question?

Comment: Doesn't look presentable

Comment: @jao This code changes the font-family css attribute based on the selected option tag, as per the question. 'My problem is, how do i change font-family depend of option value selected ?'

Comment: @GilangRizkie Updated the question with a code snippet for clarity.

Comment: I thought I saw something with font-color that's why I asked.

Comment: Its ok guys, thanks for your attention.. Solved ;) @HarryMumford-Turner